# Menu only inflates onResume the Activity

Tags: android, menu, drawer

I have an activity with `NavigationDrawerFragment`, shown here:

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
/**
 * Fragment used for managing interactions for and presentation of a navigation drawer.
 * See the <a href="https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#Interaction">
 * design guidelines</a> for a complete explanation of the behaviors implemented here.
 */
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment {

    /**
     * Remember the position of the selected item.
     */
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

    /**
     * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
     * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
     */
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

    /**
     * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
     */
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

    /**
     * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
     */
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;

    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

    private EventActivity mainActivity = null;

    public NavigationDrawerFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
        // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }

        // Select either the default item (0) or the last selected item.
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Indicate that this fragment would like to influence the set of actions in the action bar.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        mainActivity = (EventActivity) getActivity();

        mFragmentContainerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_drawer_attendee, container, false);


         ... NOT IMPORTANT ...

        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new MenuEventAdapter(getActivity(), menuAL));
        mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(mCurrentSelectedPosition, true);

        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id)
            {
                            ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
                }
        });

        return mFragmentContainerView;
    }

    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    /**
     * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
     *
     * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
     * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
     */
    public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener

        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
        // between the navigation drawer and the action bar app icon.
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        ) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) {
                    return;
                }

                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                    // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                    sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
                }

                getActivity().supportInvalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            }
        };

        // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
        // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }

        // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
    }

    private void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerListView != null) {
            mDrawerListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
        }
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        // If the drawer is open, show the global app actions in the action bar. See also
        // showGlobalContextActionBar, which controls the top-left area of the action bar.
        if (mDrawerLayout != null && isDrawerOpen()) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.global, menu);
            showGlobalContextActionBar();
        }
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        /*if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_example) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Example action.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        */
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Per the navigation drawer design guidelines, updates the action bar to show the global app
     * 'context', rather than just what's in the current screen.
     */
    private void showGlobalContextActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    }

    private ActionBar getActionBar() {
        return ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    }

    /**
     * Callbacks interface that all activities using this fragment must implement.
     */
    public static interface NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when an item in the navigation drawer is selected.
         */
        void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position);
    }
}
```

When I select an item from the drawer, it will add a new `Fragment` to the activity container.

Each fragment have it's own menu, as shown in the following example:

**EventInformationFragment.java**

```
public class EventInformationFragment extends Fragment
{
    private View rootView = null;
    private EventActivity mainActivity = null;
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    private boolean isStaff = false;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ViewGroup container = null;

    private TextView forCopy = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if(EventActivityHelper.getHelper().inSchedule)
        {
            return null;
        }

        mainActivity = (EventActivity) GlobalContents.getNowActivity();

        mainActivity.getActionBar().setTitle(R.string.Event);

        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.container = container;

        GlobalContents.dismissProgressBar();

        if(!GlobalContents.getGlobalContents().getAuthenticatedUser().isStaff())
        {
            return elaborateAttendeeView();
        }

        isStaff = true;

        return elaborateStaffView();
    }

    private View elaborateAttendeeView()
    {
         ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

    private View elaborateStaffView()
    {
         ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
    {
        if(menu.hasVisibleItems())
            menu.clear();

        if(isStaff)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.event, menu);

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        if(menu.hasVisibleItems())
            menu.clear();

        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();

        if(isStaff)
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.event, menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId())
        {
            case R.id.action_edit:
                mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .remove(mainActivity.currentFragment)
                    .remove(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .commit();

                mainActivity.currentFragment = new EventEditInformationFragment();
                mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.container, mainActivity.currentFragment).commit();

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
         ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
         ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

}
```

Here is the exact part of `EventInformationFragment` that I inflates the menu:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    if(menu.hasVisibleItems())
        menu.clear();

    if(isStaff)
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.event, menu);

    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

The problem is: when I open the `Fragment` through the `NavigationDrawerFragment`, the menu **doesn't inflate!**

In the `EventInformationFragment`, I intent to another activity, and, **onResume** this activity, the menu **inflates!**

What am I doing wrong?

Here is the activity that has the `NavigationDrawerFragment` and, at some point, `EventInformationFragment`

**EventActivity.java**

```
public class EventActivity extends ActionBarActivity 
                                implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks
{
    private static final String TAG = "EventActivity";
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    public Event currentEvent = null;

    private PagerSlidingTabStrip tabs;
    private ViewPager pager;

    /* FOR TABBING */
    private MyPagerAdapter adapter;

    public Fragment currentFragment = null;
    public Map<String, Fragment> fragments = null;
    private Bundle instance;

    public Vector<List<Lecture>> currentLectures = null;

    private Calendar[] realScheduleDays;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_fragment_and_drawer);

        currentEvent = GlobalContents.getGlobalContents().getCurrentEvent();

        GlobalContents.setNowActivity(this);

        if(GlobalContents.getGlobalContents().getAuthenticatedUser() == null)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, SignInActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
        else if(currentEvent == null)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProfileEventActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            finish();
        }
        else
        {   
            GlobalContents.getGlobalContents().setProgressBar();
            /* DRAWER */
            mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);

            DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

            setTitle(getString(R.string.Event));
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, mDrawerLayout);

            if(!EventActivityHelper.getHelper().inSchedule)
                dismissTabsForSchedule();
            else
                loadTabsForSchedule();

            /* CONTENT */
            if (savedInstanceState == null)
            {
                EventActivityHelper.getHelper();

                if(!EventActivityHelper.getHelper().inSchedule)
                {
                    currentFragment = new EventInformationFragment();

                    fragments = new HashMap<String, Fragment>();

                    fragments.put(currentFragment.getClass().getName(), currentFragment);

                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .add(R.id.container, currentFragment).commit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void loadTabsForSchedule()
    {
          ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

    public void dismissTabsForSchedule()
    {
          ... NOT IMPORTANT ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        /*fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container,
                        PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();*/
    }

    public void restoreActionBar() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
            // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
            // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
            // decide what to show in the action bar.
            //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.event, menu);
            restoreActionBar();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        GlobalContents.setNowActivity(this);
    }

    @Override  
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {     
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 

        GlobalContents.setNowActivity(this);
        switch(requestCode)
        { 
        case Constants.FOR_REFRESH:

            if(resultCode == Constants.FOR_REFRESH_OK)
            {
                currentLectures = null;
                loadTabsForSchedule();
            }

            break;
        }  
    } 

    ... NOT IMPORTANT FROM NOW ON...
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that `isStaff` is true when `onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called?

Comment: Yep, it`s always `true`.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of search and tries, I've managed to make it work.

Before I commit the `Fragment`, I've placed an `invalidateOptionsMenu()`.

It works now.